# IoT Explorer Kit registration process

Tags: robotics

how do I reinitialize an Arduino kit registration number for a new student using a kit previously registered?  We recently ordered 50 of the IoT Explorer Kits and they will be used in a robotics class that has frequent turnover, and the kits need to be used under different student accounts.

Comment: please ask the place where you register the kits ... make up names, something like `kit001` ... as it stands, the question is about the usage of an internet service, not about Arduino